# Unattended install of ilmerge

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, nuget, ilmerge, chocolatey

I'm trying to setup a large number of build agents and so far i can install all the dependencies silently (using powershell, nuget and chocolatey).
However i cannot install the tool IlMerge without the damn GUI popping up. 
Ive tried all the usual msiexec switches and they are just ignored. does anyone know of a way of getting this tool on a box in an unattended way? 
Or should i just repack the thing in zip/msi?

This is on windows server 2008 R2
If i run

```
Invoke-Expression "msiexec $installerPath\ilmerge.msi /passive"
```

I still get a security dialog.

Currently i'm just thinking ill do this:

```
Copy-Item x:\installs\ilmerge.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\ILMerge"
```

seeing as its only one file.

Comment: Fixed using GPO settings for .msi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below worked for me, no security dialogs.

```
cp ILMerge.msi \\Server\admin$
winrs -r:Server ILMerge.msi /passive
dir "\\Server\C$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge"
```

Comment: Hi ilya yeah it looks like its general security issue with a number of msi's. ill hopefully use group policy to allow these installers.

Answer (score 0):

With chocolatey you would have just needed to specify -ia '/quiet' as the package was not silent by default. This was specified by the tag notSilent and it was also in the description (http://chocolatey.org/packages/ilmerge/2.11.1103.1).

The latest package is just the executable, so you can just install it. http://chocolatey.org/packages/ilmerge